# Add JavaScript code dynamically with JSON in Asp.net - JVector Map

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2013

I am using JVector map and marking some locations on the map using [Markers](http://jvectormap.com/examples/markers-world/).
According to the documentaiton the following code can be used to mark locations.

```
 markers: [

          { latLng: [53.3574436, 9.9076650], name: 'some city' },
          { latLng: [53.3574436, 10.2127204], name: 'another city' },
          { latLng: [56.5611120, 24.0300030], name: 'one more city' }

        ]
```

In my case I am not sure how many locations I need to mark. Some times 3, some times 5. So what I want to know is, it is possible to Generate the code inside `markers : [ ]` dynamically with JSON. Or may be any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You could add code with ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerclientscriptblock(v=vs.140).aspx

Or you could do it inline in the markup with <% %> tags.